# Best design pattern to update or insert bulk data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mysql2

I wonder which is the best design pattern to update or insert bulk data in the DB.

My app uses a MVVM pattern where the Model performs "CUD" operations
and there is a QueryObject Pattern for complex "R" queries.

So for example I have some code like that:

```
const book = new BookModel(data);
const id = await book.save();
```

and other like this:

```
const bks = await new BooksQuery().orderByAuthor().whereGenre('engineering').execute();
const books = books.map((book) => new BooksViewModel(req, book));
this.render(req, res, 'books', books);
```

Let's suppose that I've to save the sort order for many books.
The question is, where does logically it go?

1. This is ugly, I think the model is misused:

```
const book = new BookModel();
const result = await book.saveSort(orderedIds);
```

or

```
const book = new BookModel(orderedIds);
const result = await book.saveSort();
```

2. More beautiful but I have to split again the entity management (maybe could be merged with the Query Object called BooksQuery...):

```
const result = await new BooksCommand().saveSort(orderedIds).execute();
```

3. Other options that I don't know.

Thank you!